# Proof of product rule using little-o definition of derivative.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, asymptotics

The derivative is most commonly defined as a limit of a difference quotient,
$$f'(x) := \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}.$$
However, the derivative can also be characterized as the unique number $f'(x)$ such that
$$f(x + h) = f(x) + f'(x)h + o(h)$$
holds. I was wondering about how to prove the product rule with this definition. Let $f, g:\mathbf R\to\mathbf R$. May we then compute the following?
$$\begin{align*}
f(x+h)\cdot g(x + h) &= (f(x) + f'(x)h + o(h))\cdot(g(x) + g'(x)h + o(h))\\
&= f(x)g(x) + (f'(x)g(x) + g'(x)f(x))h + f'(x)g'(x)h^2\\
&+ o(h)(f(x) + f'(x)h + g(x) + g'(x)h) + o(h)o(h)\\
&= f(x)g(x) + (f'(x)g(x) + g'(x)f(x))h + f'(x)g'(x)h^2 + o(h)
\end{align*}
$$
And if so, would this computation reduce the proof of the product rule to showing that $f'(x)g'(x)h^2$ is $o(h)$?

Comment: looks fine to me. $f'(x)g'(x)h^2$ is obviously $o(h)$

Comment: $f'(x)g'(x)h^2 = o(h^2)$. Given functions $u,v$ of $h$, if for all small enough $h, u(h) \le kv(h)$ for some constant $k$, then $o(u(h))$ is $o(v(h))$. So $o(h^2)$ is $o(h)$.